# What is the correct way to add an image with transparency over another image via nodes?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I have a texture which contains a number, like in the picture below. And I want to 'paste' it over the tshirt texture. I have tried using mixRGB but I have this effect in which you can see the back stripes in the number. And I would like to have it straight white.
Additionally, I would like to add a node to control the color of the number.
If I change the mixRGB node mode to lighten I can have the desired effect for the white numbers. But then I can't change the colors correctly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plug the alpha from the text image texture in the mix node.

[image]

If you are using EEVEE make sure your material has the right blend mode: (opaque is wrong)

[image]

Comment: Oh that was so easy. It did solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad i could help. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Chris' answer, you can do it this way, mix the 2 textures into a *MixRGB*, use the alpha output of your number as factor, and choose the color you want in the *MixRGB*. You can use another *UV Map* before the number texture if needed. It works fine if you don't need to change the *Principled BSDF* settings of the number (like its glossiness), otherwise Chris' answer is more convenient:

[image]